# How to get gmail inbox feed from a category

Tags: gmail, feed, atom-feed, inbox

As specified here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed, I can get a feed of unread emails under a label 'work' by simply calling https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/work/

How can we do the same thing with a category (primary, social, promotions, updates, forums) ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can get the feed for a specific tab in gmail.

Just add at the end of the atom URL one of the following labels to access tab's unread mails:

- Primary: ^smartlabel_personal
- Social: ^smartlabel_social
- Promotions: ^smartlabel_promo
- Updates: ^smartlabel_notification
- Forums: ^smartlabel_group

Eg: [https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/^smartlabel_personal](https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/%5Esmartlabel_personal)

*Not official source (see section 8)*: http://add0n.com/gmail-notifier-updated.html